# How to get a String variable's value from VSCode's Watch window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't quite believe I'm having to ask this, but **how do I obtain the full value of a String variable in the Watch window in VSCode**?

From here:

[image: I want this string]

I'm trying to get the multi-line string that I can see in the tooltip into my clipboard.

EDIT: If I expand out the treeview of values here in the Watch window, I can see deeper levels of the variable's object hierarchy.  As suggested in ChatterOne's original answer, I could have copied the values from "primitive" types from the rght-clck context menu, however, this value is awkwardly a String type, so isn't working in the same way as primitives would.  As shown here:

[image: can't copy String]

Note that only the lowest level (fullExceptionString.value[0]) has the copy value context menu item, but it's greyed out here, and I wanted the entire string not individual chars.

Comment: I've started to use the method of just pasting the variable name into the Debug window, from there I can select "Copy Value" and get the full string, unfortunately including the double quotes, but alas, I can at least copy it now.

Comment: update:  Still looking for an answer to this!

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty absurd. I use my debug window to look at the SQL I am about to run, where I can copy and paste it to test it. I have an SQL object whoś toString() is the sql to run. If I copy value I get ¨select bla...."Literally that! Incluidng quotes and ellipsis! Nobody wants that! Why is it not the full string? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this but you can try putting this in the variable watch

```
*(char (*)[3091])variableName
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're selecting an expression with nested values.

If you right-click on anything "below" that (meaning in the same tree) but with a primitive value (meaning not nested), you'll see a `copy value` menu entry.

What you want is probably in the `value` entry. Expand that and right-click on the entry for which you need to copy the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ChatterOne.  I've updated my question with the suggestion you provided.  Still can't work it out though :(  I must be being daft...

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's related to this (the original issue is about python, but it's actually for most languages)? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1398

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is to cast variable in Watch pane:
e.g. Type in "(char *)variableName" instead of "variableName".
It is annoying but works.

Comment: Oops, I can watch the value as string but am still unable to copy string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you may copy/paste the output to any JSON formatter to work with your data.

In a debug console: `copy(JSON.stringify(yourVarialbeHere));`

I tope it helps.